# Assign edge direction based on vertex strength

Tags: r, igraph

I have an undirected graph. I want to assume edge direction based on vertex strength, so that I created a directed graph with all edges directed towards the higher strength vertex in each edge.

The only solution I found was as.directed, but this seems to only be able to assign random direction to each edge.

e.g. I have a simple graph of 5 vertices and 6 edges

```
V(g)

+ 5/5 vertices, named, from 003341a:
[1] A B C D E
```

```
strength(g)

 A  B  C  D  E 
81 40 21 30 30
```

```
E(g)

+ 6/6 edges from 003341a (vertex names):
[1] A--B A--C A--D A--E B--E D--E
```

I would like to set directionality based on strength, such that the direction is towards the higher strength vertex.

Here is the output of dput(g) as requested:

```
dput(g)

structure(list(5, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
3), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
6), c(0, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    list(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), list(weight = c(30L, 
    21L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 10L))), <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

This the directionality I want to achieve (but do not know how to get currently):

```
E(g)

+ 6/6 edges from 003341a (vertex names):
[1] A<-B A<-C A<-D A<-E B<-E D<>E
```

Comment: Could you paste the output of `dput(net)` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question! One possible solution is to add the strength as an vertex attribute and generate a new edge attribute based on the difference between the corresponding vertices.

```
V(g)$strength <- strength(g)
ids <- get.edges(g, 1:ecount(g))
E(g)$weight1 <- V(g)$strength[ids[,1]] - V(g)$strength[ids[,2]]
E(g)$weight2 <- V(g)$strength[ids[,2]] - V(g)$strength[ids[,1]]
```

The next step is to take a look at the adjacency-matrix of the graph:

```
m0 <- get.adjacency(g, sparse = F)
m0
```

```
> m0
  A B C D E
A 0 1 1 1 1
B 1 0 0 0 1
C 1 0 0 0 0
D 1 0 0 0 1
E 1 1 0 1 0
```

In this case we have a symmetric matrix, which translates into an undirected graph. The idea now is to delete all the entries (representing edges) connecting 'weaker' vertices with stronger ones. In order to do this we take the previously calculated edge weight into consideration. We do this for both 'directions' of the matrix (upper and lower bounds).

```
m <- get.adjacency(g, type = "lower", attr = "weight1", sparse = F)
m1 <- get.adjacency(g, type = "upper", attr = "weight2", sparse = F)
```

If we combine the matrices we get a matrix with both positve and negative edges.

```
m2 <- m1+m
```

```
> m2
   A   B   C   D   E
A  0 -41 -60 -51 -51
B 41   0   0   0 -10
C 60   0   0   0   0
D 51   0   0   0   0
E 51  10   0   0   0
```

Since we are only interested in edges directed at vertices with *higher* strength, we delete negative entries in the original binary adjacency-matrix.

```
m0[m2 < 0] <- 0
```

```
> m0
  A B C D E
A 0 0 0 0 0
B 1 0 0 0 0
C 1 0 0 0 0
D 1 0 0 0 1
E 1 1 0 1 0
```

We can build the graph from here:

```
g2 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m0, mode = "directed")
plot(g2)
```

The resulting graph looks something like this:

[image]

---

**EDIT** I just realized that you already have the desired pairing and direction of the edges. In this case you can use the `mode` or `directed` argument that a lot of `igraph` functions offer. See for example:

```
?graph_from_data_frame
```

Let's say you generated your graph from an existing edgelist (`el`), then you could simply write something like this:

```
g2 <- graph_from_data_frame(el, directed = T)
```

Comment: Thanks - you had the problem correct before the edit. I showed the direction I wanted to achieve, rather than what I already had. I can update the question to make that more clear. I'll give the code a try this evening. Thanks again.

Comment: Works great, and on my larger dataset too. Thanks again - much appreciated.